# Boostrap dropdown not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the bootstrap dropdown work. The same code works perfectly when executed in standalone manner, however when I integrate it with my existing code, it doesn't work. The button displays, but doesn't dropdown!
The files required for bootstrap and jquery are installed locally, not using CDN.

```
this.renderLaunchJobs = function( data ) {

       var allData = myModel.getMetaData();

       workingJobData = {};
       backupJobData  = {};

var html = '<table style="width:70%"';
        html += '<tr>';
        html += '<td> Build # </td>';
        html += ' <td> <input type="text" name="firstname" style="width:50%;"> </td>';
        html += '<td> </td>'
        html += '<td>  <input type="radio" name="group" id="production" checked>';
        html += '<label for="production"> Production</label> </td>';
        html += '<td> <input type="radio" name="group" id="private">';
        html += '<label for="private">Private</label> </td>';
        html += '</tr>';
//adding transfer method
        html += '<tr>';
        html += '<td> Transfer method </td>';
        html += '<td>';
        html += myUtils.getDropDownBox("transfermethod_id","width:50%;", workingSubJobData.transfermethod_id, allData['transfermethods'], "id", "nickname" );
        html += '</td>';
        html += '</tr>';    

//adding nested dropdown

        html += '<tr>';
        html += '<td>';
        html += '<div class="container">';
//      html += '    <h2>Multi-Level Dropdowns</h2>';
    //  html += '    <!--<p>In this example, we use jQuery to open multi-level dropdowns on click (see script section below).</p>-->';
        html += '    <div class="dropdown">';
        html += '        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Tutorials';
        html += '            <span class="caret"></span></button>';
        html += '        <ul class="dropdown-menu">';
        html += '            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML</a></li>';
        html += '            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">CSS</a></li>';
        html += '            <li>';
        html += '                <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">New dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>';
        html += '                <ul class="dropdown-menu">';
        html += '                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>';
        html += '                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>';
        html += '                    <li>';
        html += '                        <a class="test" href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>';
        html += '                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">';
        html += '                            <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>';
        html += '                            <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>';
        html += '                        </ul>';
        html += '                    </li>';
        html += '                </ul>';
        html += '            </li>';
        html += '        </ul>';
        html += '    </div>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '</td>';
        html += '</tr>';    

       html += '</table>';

      var jobs = data;
      if( jobs.length == 0 ) {
          html += " <br> <font color='red' size='3'> <strong> No Jobs found to Launch. Please add a Job profile. </strong> </font> <br>";

      } else {

           html += '<br> <br> <br>';
           html += myJobs.getJobsHtmlTable( jobs, allData );
     }

     $('#page_holder').html( html );

     $('.tree2').treegrid({
                    expanderExpandedClass: 'icon-minus-sign',
                    expanderCollapsedClass: 'icon-plus-sign',
                    initialState: 'collapsed'
     });


 }
```

`Index.html` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class=" js no-touch rgba hsla backgroundsize cssanimations csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions fontface generatedcontent svg inlinesvg svgclippaths boxsizing lastchild js no-touch rgba hsla backgroundsize cssanimations csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions fontface generatedcontent svg inlinesvg svgclippaths boxsizing lastchild js no-touch rgba hsla backgroundsize cssanimations csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions fontface generatedcontent svg inlinesvg svgclippaths boxsizing lastchild">

<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=IE7">
<title>A Bootstrap Project</title>

 <!-- bootbox -->
<!--
  <script src="js/bootbox/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootbox/bootbox.min.js"></script>
-->
<link href="treegrid/bootstrap-2.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<link   rel="stylesheet" href="js/bootbox/bootstrap.min.css">

<!--Favicon -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
<!-- Style -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/navigation.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/customize.css">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/ie_lt9.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie_not.css">
<!--<![endif]-->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
<script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="js/highlight.pack.js"></script> <!-- syntax highlighting -->
<script src="js/fastclick.js"></script> <!-- remove 300ms delay on tap -->
<script src="js/pagify.js"></script><!-- dynamic page loading -->
<script src="js/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js"></script> <!-- monitor hashchanges -->
<script src="js/jquery.tooltipster.min.js"></script> <!-- tooltips -->
<script src="js/jquery-ui.widget.min.js"></script> <!-- for selective tables -->
<script src="js/select2.js"></script> <!-- select2 -->
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script> <!-- all custom scripts -->
<script src="js/screenshot.js"></script> <!-- all custom scripts -->

<script src="js/utils.js"> </script>
<script src="js/model.js"> </script>
<script src="js/render.js"> </script>
<script src="js/reports.js"> </script>
<script src="js/comments.js"> </script>
<script src="js/settings.js"> </script>
<script src="js/jobs.js"> </script>

<!-- auto complete -->

<script src="js/autocomplete/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/autocomplete/jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/autocomplete/jquery.ui.widget.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/autocomplete/jquery.ui.position.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/autocomplete/jquery.ui.autocomplete.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/autocomplete/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css"/>



<!-- date Picker -->
<!--  <script src="datepicker/jquery.min.js"></script>  -->
  <script src="datepicker/jquery.plugin.js"></script>
  <script src="datepicker/jquery.datepick.js"></script>
  <link   rel="stylesheet" href="datepicker/jquery.datepick.css">

<!-- Boot Box -->

  <script src="js/bootbox/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootbox/bootbox.min.js"></script>


<!---  Tree Grid -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="treegrid/css/jquery.treegrid.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="treegrid/js/jquery.treegrid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="treegrid/js/jquery.treegrid.bootstrap2.js"></script>

<!--
  <link   rel="stylesheet" href="js/bootbox/bootstrap.min.css">
-->
<!--
<link rel="stylesheet" href="datepicker/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="datepicker/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="datepicker/jquery-ui.js"></script>
-->

<!--
<link rel="stylesheet" href="datepicker/style.css">
-->

<link href="fileupload/uploadfile.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="fileupload/jquery.uploadfile.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >

$(document).click(function() {
  $("#globalwarningdiv").removeClass("visible");
  $("#globalinfodiv").removeClass("visible");
});

$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  $("#globalwarningdiv").removeClass("visible");
  $("#globalinfodiv").removeClass("visible");
});

$("#globalwarningdiv").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$("#globalinfodiv").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).ready( function() {

   myModel.getAllData();

});

</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="content_wrapper">

  <div class="logo"><a href=""><img src="images/logo.png"></a></div>
      <div id='login-menu' style='display:block;' >
<!--
        <div class="mobile_menu_toggle"><a class="icon_arrow_down" href="#">Menu</a></div>
                <ul class="sidenav">
                <li class="" id="menu-login"> <a href="Javascript: renderHtml.renderLoginPage(); ">Log-in</a> </li>
        </ul>
-->

      </div>

<!--
      <div id='logout-menu' style='display:none;' >
        <div class="mobile_menu_toggle"><a class="icon_arrow_down" href="#">Menu</a></div>
                <ul class="sidenav">
                <li class="" id="menu-login"> <a href="Javascript: renderHtml.verifyDepartment(); ">Log-in</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

-->


 </div>

    <div class="content" style="display:block;">
        <div id="page_holder" style="display: block;">
            <h3> Welcome. </h3>
    <!--    <script src="js/components.js"></script> -->
         </div> 
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

I have checked to make sure there is no problem with dependencies. Bootstrap and jquery are perfectly loaded into the page. Other bootstrap components except dropdown works well.
What am I missing? :(

Comment: This is just JS code. Please share your HTML adn etc. as well in the code, so we can work on it.

Comment: where is the modal `data-target`?

Comment: `data-target` did not matter. I did try with `data-target="#page_holder"`, still didn't work.

Comment: @apollo added html file!

Comment: A JSFiddle would be better..

Comment: @RohitPujar Buddy, we all need you to share your complete code with your local CSS files, JS files and HTML code. In order to do this on stackoverflow, you need to go to a website that supports online editing like JSFiddle or Bootply. And you have to create the same project there for us to reproduce the error you are talking about. Just sharing your JS or CSS or HTML seperately won't work since we do not know your project by heart. We are just trying to help. Help us, so we can help you.

Comment: i suggest u to escape new line chars in js string. Engine works **10times** faster then. Not use "+" sign. :)